# Ansible WinRM with Certificate Auth stopped by impersonation token

Tags: authentication, ansible, certificate, winrm, ansible-awx

I'm trying to connect to multiple Windows servers using Certificate based authentication through Ansible. On the majority of servers there is no problem, however, a few of them give this error :

```
"certificate: An attempt has been made to operate on an impersonation token by a thread that is not currently impersonating a client.  (extended fault data: {'transport_message': 'Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 500', 'http_status_code': 500, 'wsmanfault_code': '1309', 'fault_code': 's:Receiver', 'fault_subcode': 'w:InternalError'})",
```

All the servers share the same configuration. This is why I don't know why this error is showing.

Does someone have an idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure out this issue? Im also getting this error